# TFS Run PowerShell on Targe Machines not working?

Tags: powershell, tfs, devops

I'm Running powershell script using TFS build step - Run PowerShell on Target Machines but it does not work.

Here's how script looks like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'Bginfo.lnk'
```

It runs shurtcut that refreshes information on pc desktop using bginfo.exe - script works fine when its executed manualy.

TFS executes that script, but it does not work - bginfo is not refreshed.
If I add to that script line that creates new file it also will be created. 
Why it does not automatically update background using specified shurtcut?

Comment: Who's desktop are you trying to change on the remote machine, yours? Is the TFS build step executing the script with your credentials? Are you using the `/ALL` and `/NOLICPROMPT` switches? How about `/LOG:C:\gbinfo.log` to see if it is executing at all?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue. Tried command line, batch script, PowerShell steps with `/TIMER:0 /SILENT /NOLICPROMPT` set and with the service account which has administrator's privilege. Seems it only works when run the script manually on target machine.

In this case, if you want to refresh the system info automatically, you can use task schedule to run the Bginfo script in target machine. Reference below threads :

- [BGinfo not running silently](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ea3d6d3-1fab-42f8-9ffd-8ec4c65c71b0/bginfo-not-running-silently?forum=w7itproui)
- [BGInfo on Windows Server 2012](https://idoneitmyself.com/2012/12/30/bginfo-on-windows-server-2012/)
- [Making BgInfo work in Windows 2012 / Windows 2016](https://notesfrommwhite.net/2014/05/26/making-bginfo-work-in-windows-2012/)